# C# Charts - how to find X-Axis co-ords of zoomable zone?

Tags: c#, charts

I have created a small app to try and help me understand some of the Charting features I need to use in another app. In the app you use the charting features to drag the mouse the highlight the area you want to zoom into see the image below:

[image]

At the bottom right of the form you see two labels one with 0 and the other with 3000. What I want to put in here is the value of the min and max x-axis values that my mouse has drawn, in other words the grey area above which is around 37 and 63 on x-axis. This must be a mouse event but it seems to be hidden from me. Do you know how to get this please.

I tried various things including:

```
private void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

            lbl_min_value.Text = ca.AxisX.Minimum.ToString();
            lbl_max_value.Text = ca.AxisX.Maximum.ToString();

            // lbl_min_value.Text = e.X.ToString();
        }
```

If you would like to play with the code then please clone it from GitHub @
https://github.com/zizwiz/Test_Charts

Comment: The textbox is a string so in the example in the link they parse : double min_val = double.Parse(txtbx_min.Text) + 1; //Zero based

Comment: Try this: `private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left))
    {
        Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
        double vx = ax.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
        Console.WriteLine(vx);
    }
}`

Comment: For the MouseUp ypu could use: `var x1 = ax.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
var x2 = ax.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;`

Comment: @TaW your last suggestion is perfect, thanks for the help.